# Detect ie 7-9 desktop versions (without ie in windows phone)

Tags: internet-explorer

I have that code:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="/sites/all/themes/infood/ie/ie.html"</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="/sites/all/themes/infood/ie/ie.html"</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="/sites/all/themes/infood/ie/ie.html"</script>
<![endif]-->
```

But when i try load site page in windows phone 7, load only ie.html becouse version is ie9

So how it's fix up

Comment: You probably shouldn't use browser engine versions to detect the screen layout as well. In fact you probably shouldn't use IE conditional comments, much less Javascript reloads in them in the first place. What are you trying to accomplish and why can't you use feature detection, browser sniffing, or responsive design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it not possible that for all conditions you are returning /sites/all/themes/infood/ie/ie.html?

Comment: in windows phone ie, working only condition for ie9 
I decided allow access to site in ie9 and the above, thanks

Comment: there are not many WP7 left and it shipped with IE7, not sure if it was updated to IE9 or not. WP8 has IE 10 on it. The conditional comments will be ignored with IE11, which should ship with WP8.1 this winter/spring FWIW.

Comment: i have wp7.8 with ie9